# Turning JSON.parse() return type to an array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have defined a file called note-data.json which contains json data. In the following code a variable of type of array called notes is declared. What I want to achieve is that the program read the json file save it in the noteString variable and then make a array of object with JSON.parse() from noteString and put it into notes array. So I can add new objects to the json file. But when the programme gets to the line note.push() it complains since, I think, the type of notes has turned to a string and push is not define for string. How can I get around this issue?

Please ignore the fact that if the json file is not provided the the program crashes.

My code:

```
const addNote = (title, body) => {
  let notes= [];
  const note = {

    title,
    body
  };

  const notesString = fs.readFileSync('node-data.json', 'utf8');
  notes = JSON.parse(notesString);

  notes.push(note);
  fs.writeFileSync('node-data.json', JSON.stringify(note));
}
```

File note-data.json:

```
{"title":"Greeting","body":"Hello"}
```

Comment: Your `{"title":"Greeting","body":"Hello"}` is an object with properties, and when you do this `notes = JSON.parse(notesString);` your turn `notes` into that object, hence `notes.push(note);` won't work not being an array anymore.

Comment: Wrap the content of `note-data.json` in an array: `[{"title":"Greeting","body":"Hello"}]`

Comment: @Andreas - I wrapped it to an array of objects, but after execution the array of object gets overwritten by an object. It does not add the new object to the array.

Comment: You missed an `s`. You're writing `note` to the file, not `notes`

Comment: @LGSon - That is the issue I want to tackle. How I can say instead of returning an object by JSON.parse(), return and array of objects

Comment: For adding new object, instead of overwritten you need to take the clone of old objects in a variable and need to append that fully with new datas.

Comment: @JaredSmith - You are right, but the issue happens before that line. the compiler complaint is for notes.push(note);

Comment: By doing what Andreas suggested in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130372/turning-json-parse-return-type-to-an-array-of-object?noredirect=1#comment93154504_53130372)

Comment: @Hossein and? Andreas already told you how to fix your json file, but if you don't make the change I suggested then the program will keep throwing the same error in the same place.

Comment: Or you do `notes.push(JSON.parse(notesString));` if `notesString` only contain that single object. If the `noteString` holds several object it has to have the `[]` wrapped around them, where each object is separated with a comma, or else it won't be properly formatted as an array of objects.

Comment: Thank you all, I figured out what was going on. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are fumbling with your variables here. From what I understood - you want to read JSON from a file and append that JSON to an array, right? Following code will help you do just that

```
const addNote = (title, body) => {

  let notes= []; //Declare an array
  const note = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('node-data.json', 'utf8')); //read and parse file contents
  notes.push(note); //Append new JSON to your array

  //This line below appears to have no purpose ??
  fs.writeFileSync('node-data.json', JSON.stringify(note));
}
```